# ¿Qué ocurre si se despierta un proceso despierto?

Tags: c++, c

Se me a dado una porción de dos códigos "Proceso Productor" y "Proceso Consumidor" (las funciones se llaman `void producer()` y `void consumer()`, respectivamente).

Ambos códigos son funciones tipo `void` y se ejecutan en paralelo modificando los valores de dos variables globales llamadas `INT itemCount=0;` y `const BUFFER_SIZE=5;`.

Ahora, en una parte del código de `producer` dice lo siguiente:

```
if (itemCount==1)
{
   weakup(consumer);
}
```

En el caso de que `consumer` este despierto, y se utilice este fragmento del código es posible que el programa falle?

Comment: O es C o es C++... no puede ser los dos a la vez. ¿Y qué es eso de "*modificando los valores de dos variables globales llamadas ... `const BUFFER_SIZE=5`*"?

Comment: Por otro lado la pregunta no tiene demasiado sentido... el encabezado habla de un proceso dormido... y en el cuerpo de despertar a uno que ya lo está :S

Comment: Me disculpo, me referia a un proceso despierto, que se le despierte con un wakeup(), espero que se entienda

Answer (score 0):

Deberías hacer una verificación de su estado, normalmente si un proceso está en un estado y lo intentas colocar en el mismo estado, debería crear algún tipo de de Exception, por seguridad al menos, no conozco el funcionamiento interior de wakeup, pero posiblemente sea que comience el proceso por donde iba antes, o en el caso en que menos te conviene es que se reinicie todo el proceso.

Comment: Dudo mucho que despertar un proceso pueda provocar que se reinicie del todo y empiece desde cero... despertar un proceso no tiene efectos sobre la memoria (y esto incluye su pila). Para conseguir eso tendrías que matar el proceso en cuestión y crear otro con el mismo punto de entrada.